# How can one use /etc/paths.d to add a path with spaces in it to $PATH?

Tags: bash, vmware, path

I recently installed VMware Fusion 10 on a Mac running macOS 10.12.6. After doing so, my bash PATH is broken.  I traced the problem to a /etc/paths.d path file that Fusion installed; it contains the following entry (with no newline):

`/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public`

Note the space in the pathname.  With this present, on starting a shell I get an error:

```
-bash: export: `Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/Library/TeX/texbin': not a valid identifier
```

And my resulting PATH is corrupted.  I tried adding a newline, putting the path in double-quotes, and putting a backslash before the space; all of these produce an error (sometimes different errors).  For example, adding the backslash or wrapping with double-quotes gives the same error.  Both changes together gives:

```
-bash: test: /Users/loredo/Library/Commands:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Applications/VMware: binary operator expected
-bash: test: /Users/loredo/Library/Commands:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Applications/VMware: binary operator expected
-bash: test: /usr/local/var/rbenv/shims:/Users/loredo/Library/Commands:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Applications/VMware: binary operator expected
-bash: export: `Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/Library/TeX/texbin:.:/usr/texbin:/usr/local/cuda/bin': not a valid identifier
```

I'm beginning to wonder if `path_helper` may be unable to handle such a use case.  Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: My `/etc/paths.d/com.vmware.fusion.public` contains `/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public` and in Terminal `echo $PATH` outputs: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public`  I have no problem with my `PATH` or executing e.g. `vmrun`, which is in the `/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public` directory, so having the _space_ is not an issue. Your `PATH` is being messed up elsewhere! Have you modified `/etc/paths` or have you added a `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` and if so are you modifying the `PATH` in any of these files?

Comment: In Terminal, what is the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: Thanks, @user3439894, your hunch was right. Some ancient PATH manipulation crud in my .profile on that machine was at fault. Updating it fixed the problem. If you post this as an answer I'll happily select it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My `/etc/paths.d/com.vmware.fusion.public` contains:

```
 /Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public
```

In Terminal, `echo $PATH` outputs:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public
```

I have no problem with my `PATH` or executing e.g. `vmrun`, which is in the `/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public` directory, so having the *space* is not an issue. Your `PATH` is being messed up elsewhere!

Have you modified `/etc/paths` or have you added a `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile`, and if so are you modifying the `PATH`in any of these files?

Comment: Thank you for the good detective work. Indeed, the problem was some ancient .profile PATH manipulation functions. Once fixed, all is well.

Answer (score 2):

So I'll try and give this one the ol college attempt.  So after messing around with this for about an hour I came to the conclusion that `path_helper` - ***the native app that constructs a `PATH` environment variable from `/etc/paths` and `/etc/paths.d`*** doesn't play well with paths that have spaces in them, ie. thus why you're experiencing your current situation.

So my hacky solution to get this working, is to create a symlink from,

`/Applications/VMware Fusion.app`

to

`/Applications/VMwareFusion.app`

using the below command,

`ln -sf /Applications/Vmware Fusion.app /Applications/VmwareFusion.app`

Then edit `/etc/paths.d/com.vmware.fusion.public` and change the one line in that file to look like the below,

`/Applications/VMwareFusion.app/Contents/Public/`

Then obviously start a new shell session or reinit.

This solution works great for me using the fish shell.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input, but the comment by @user3439894 was right. On one of my machines, I had a .profile in place that used some PATH manipulation commands that I cribbed from Fink and elsewhere long ago. It was one of those commands that was at fault. Replacing it made all well, even though there are spaces in the paths in PATH. So `path_helper` was not at fault; at least in my case, it is correctly handling spaces in paths.